# Android Button Text Color Always Pink

Tags: android, xml, button, state

I am trying to change both the button text color and the button background color when the button toggles between selected state and not. The background works perfectly, but the text just shows as pink (the default `colorPrimary`, which I have changed).

`res/drawable/map_button_background.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

`res/drawable/map_button_text.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false">
        <color android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </item>

    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <color android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

`res/styles/styles.xml`

```
<style name="Button.Map">
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/map_button_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/map_button_text</item>
</style>
```

Also, the text color never changes, it just stays pink all the time. I tried adding `<item android:color="@color:/colorPrimary"/>` to be used as a default, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas on what's causing it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a a few problems.

First, your `<item>` elements should have the `android:color` attribute on them directly, not in a child `<color>` element.

Second, `android:textColor` needs to refer to a color resource (or a literal color value).

You have placed your `map_button_text` resource in your `res/drawable` folder, which tells Android to interpret it as a Drawable, not a color.

If you move that file to `res/color` and refer to it via `@color/map_button_text` you should get what you want.

Finally, you should also define a default state for your selector (one without any `android:state_` attributes).

Your final XML should look something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_selected="false"/>

    <!-- Default state -->
    <item android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Awesome answer Bryan, I had some issues with this and after some ours I realized it was because the directory it was in. It was inside `res/drawable` instead of  `res/color`.